# How to work with $GLOBALS

Tags: php, superglobals

I have 2 different php files, and in one of the file I created a global array

```
$GLOBALS['system'] = array(
    'mysqli' => array(
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'database'  => 'database'
    )
);
```

How can I be able to use this array in another file e.g.

```
$GLOBALS['system']['mysql']['host'];
```

Comment: You have to include the file containing the globals in the other file. A better bet would be to use session variables.

Comment: 1. *How to work with $GLOBALS* Don't use them, that simple 2. `Include` the other file into your first file

Comment: But if I have to use the array inside a class ?

Comment: Pass it as argument..

Comment: How can I use sesseion to be able to access the array anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$GLOBALS['system'] = array();
```

This is unnecessary. Just do

```
$system = array();
```

Now, you can use `$system` anywhere you want (in other includes, etc), but the catch is that functions won't see it [due to scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). That means that each function doesn't have access to `$system` because it's not in the global scope (and that's a good thing because what if you needed to use `$system` inside a function?) Now, you can always fall back to

```
function foo() {
     echo $GLOBALS['system'];
}
```

But that's clunky and it relies on `$system` being defined somewhere and not changing. So let's inject it instead

```
function foo($system) {
     echo $system;
}
foo($system);
```